# Python Logging library interacts with socket communication. How to disable that?

Tags: python, sockets, logging

I have simple client and server in python which communicates using domain socket.
Protocol for communication is as follows. First send 8 char long string length (0 filled if necessary, eg: 00000008) and then send the actual string (eg. "password" for above length).

Client is able to send some message to server successfully, but when server uses sendString to send some message, client does not recieve number as first string. It recieves some loggging related message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Eg.
Length of string being received : INFO:roo

Command code which has send/receive/logging related code

```
def setupLogging(suffix):
   logger = logging.getLogger('root')
   FORMAT = "[%(filename)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
   logging.basicConfig(f=FORMAT)
   formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
   HDLR = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE)
   HDLR.setFormatter(formatter)
   logger.addHandler(HDLR)
   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   return logger


def sendString(connSock, inputString, logger):
    strLen = len(inputString)
    fStrLen = str(strLen).zfill(8)
    logger.debug("Length of string being sent : " + fStrLen)
    connSock.sendall(fStrLen)
    logger.debug("Data being sent : " + inputString)
    connSock.sendall(inputString)

def receiveString(connSock, logger):
    fStrLen = connSock.recv(8)
    logger.debug("Length of string being received : " + fStrLen)
    strLen = int(fStrLen)
    str = connSock.recv(strLen)
    logger.debug("Data received : " + str)
    return str
```

Server sample code:

```
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection, client_address = serverSocket.accept()
....
        data = receiveString(connection, logger)
        dataStrIO = StringIO.StringIO(data)
        ....
        ....
        sendString(connection, "Dummy", logger)
....
```

Client:

```
 sendString(connSock, "Some string", logger)
    # Problem when parsing first number , at this line int(fStrLen)
    receiveString(connection, logger)
```

Comment: Are you connecting these two applications via STDIN/STDOUT?  Can you create a separate pipe to connect the two? And, if not, you may want to at least ensure that STDERR isn't forwarded to STDOUT (so that if you pipe STDOUT of one to STDIN of the other, that STDERR isn't being redirected also to the second process).

Comment: These applications are connected using domain socket. They are not connected via STDIN/STDOUT. At least, I have not coded it that way. Do you know how I can check that? Logging from both application goes to two different files, so STDOUT is different. I feel same way about STDERR.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by resetting stdout and stderror to /dev/null. Thanks a lot for your help. I highly appreciate it..